# Prime ring with identity and finite ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-groups, ideals

> Having some non-zero finite ideal $I$ of prime ring with identity $R$ prove that $R$ is also finite.

My only guess would be to show that if $R$ was infinite, only a finite number of its elements would be non-zero (basing on the definition of a prime ring). However, I'm struggling to find something to start with. I would be greatful for a direction of thought or a reference to a similar task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $I$ has left annihilator zero, the map $R\to End(I_R)$ which sends $r$ to the endomorphism of $I$ given by left multiplication by $r$ is an injective ring homomorphism. But $End(I_R)$ is of course finite since $I$ is.

We can continue to conclude that $R$ is simple (any Artinian prime ring is) and $I=R$, and that $R$ is a matrix ring over a finite field.

Comment: Could you please clarify the transition to Artinian ring? Everything else seems clear.

Comment: @youtur A finite ring is artinian. An artinian prime ring is simple.  Have I covered everything?

Comment: But why is $R$ finite? I supposed that was a result of $R$ being simple with a finite non-zero ideal.

Comment: @youtur No, it is the other way around. I pointed out that $R$ injects into a finite ring, so it is finite.  THEN we can say it is simple.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the part I was missing.

Comment: @youtur Glad to help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75096/discussion-between-youtur-and-rschwieb).